# How can i combine crystal reports and JAVA SWT?

Tags: java, crystal-reports, swt

I have to create reports from my application (java, SWT). For reports, I am using crystal reports, but I have a problem, I can't find SWT code that enables me to open (create)  and save the report. I have found Swing code that enables me to do that, but I can't find SWT code. So can somebody explain me, or give me a code, or tutorial that will help me to do that. 
Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

You could try embedding the crystal reports swing components inside your swt application using `org.eclipse.swt.awt.SWT_AWT`.  For more information on how that class can be used check out this [article](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t60541.html).

Answer (score 0):

We just implemented an SWT viewer in SWT, but this was only possible by writing a custom ActiveX component, that wraps the Crystal Reports ActiveX control.

The ActiveX of crystal in not usable by SWT directly. If you are interested, we could offer some commercial implementation help.

Comment: We just modified our Crystal Reports Roadmap to dropping this ClosedSource piece of crap altogether and replacing it with Jasper. We just ahad a case where different report versions were in SVN, and no way to get a reliable diff. Awful.